# What is the relationship between the sub-items and the main one on Oxford Dictionary?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, dictionaries

Oxford Dictionary (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/just) gives a bunch of definitions about “just”

there are 3 sub-items in 4th item, one of them is pointed out by blue rectangle in the following image.

[image]

What is the relationship between the sub-items and the main one?

Could all of 3 sub-items could be a piece of meanings of "Simply", I guess not.

sub-item 4.2 gives

> Used as a polite formula for giving permission or making a request.

and gives this example

> just help yourselves

if this is one piece of meanings of the main item, namely, "Simply", the following sentence would sound normal

> Simply help yourselves

which actually sounds uncommon, any ideas?

Besides, neither Oxford dictionary (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/simply) nor Cambridge dictionary (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/simply) has a piece of meaning similar to this one (shows politeness).

Comment: Those are closely related, derived subsenses/subdefinitions.

Comment: Why do you think they have to be clearly related? See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/just where those meanings are all listed as separate entries under "Adverb". (Definitions 5, 2, & 7)

Comment: @CJDennis The first one in your link is also in my link, namely, "Only, simply, merely". Which is the most ambiguous piece to me. Under my research, there are 5 different meanings derived from "simply", that's why I split them down.

Comment: As you say, the meanings are different. Why do you think different meanings have to be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three sub-usages are clear substitutes for **simply** - each one in a slightly different way.

4.1: ***they're just great***

Their condition of being great is not bound to a complicated formula like *they're kind of great but with the exception of ... and actually...*. No, they are great. Period. It's this simple. They are ***simply*** great.

4.2: ***just help yourselves***

Don't go the complicated way of asking someone for help. Take the simple way. ***Simply*** help yourselves.

4.3: ***it might just help***

I don't know. You perhaps need a complex solution. But it could also be that this simple solution works for you. This could simply be your solution. This might simply be the help you need. This might ***simply*** help.

Of cause, we don't think of 'simply' or 'just' in such a detailedness when we use them. We use them intuitively, but the intuition checks the appropriateness of the usage against such thoughts in a quick, unknown, but reliable manner.

Comment: *Simply help yourselves* really sounds uncommon, right?

Comment: Well, yes, it's common to use _just_ in that specific situation but with the same meaning. The idea why it sounds uncommon is simple: we are not used to it.